# Solve $x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k (1-x)^k$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I am given a sequence $p_0,p_1,...$ whose sum is 1. It is a probability density function, but I am not given any specific formula about it. Consider it arbitrary.

Is it possible to solve $x$ in terms of $p_0,p_1,...$ from the following formula?

$$x =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k (1-x)^k$$

It is known that the solution always exists and that $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Is the summation really going to $\infty$ or to a large number ? The problem is very interesting from a numerical point of view but I do not see how we could handle it in the case of $k\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the intermediate value theorem to show that there is always a solution in that interval.  Moreover, since the left side is increasing while the right side is decreasing, there is only one solution in the interval.

**Finding** the solution is another matter.  In general there will be no closed form solution.  Numerical methods can be used.

EDIT: If $t = 1 - x$, you can write the equation as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q_k t^k = 0$ where $q_0 = p_0 - 1$, $q_1 = p_1 + 1$, $q_k =p_k$ otherwise.  You can then express the solution as a power series using the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Comment: Hi Robert, can you elaborate on your statement: ”Since the left side is increasing while the right side is decreasing , there is only one solution in the interval”. Thanks

Comment: Two interesting cases for particular distributions:  If $p_k = 2^{-k+1}$ for all $k$, then $x$ is the reciprocal of the golden ratio. And if $p_k = \frac1{n}$ for all $k<n$ and zero for $k \geq n$ then in the limit as $n \to \infty$, $x$ approaches $n^{-1/2}$ fairly rapidly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already coded an algorithm for solving the equation using the monotonicity you are mentioning. However, I would still like to know if somebody is aware of a closed form solution based on infinite sums, powers, binomial coefficients, product-sequences, etc. applied to the given $p_k$ sequence.

Comment: @Matthieu The difference between the two sides is (strictly) monotone.